# merge columns from common files from different directories and rename the column header form the directory it came from?

Tags: perl

I am stuck badly with my Perl code. I want to merge one column called 'value' from a common file called 'file.txt'from different directories. All these files have the same number of rows. These files have multiple columns but I am interested in merging only one column called 'value'. I want to create one file that has merged all the 'value' column but the header of the column should be named from the directory it came from.

Directory-A
File.txt

```
ID  Value location
 1   50     9
 2   56     5
 3   26     5
```

Directory-B
File.txt

```
ID  Value location
 1   07      9
 2   05      2
 3   02      5
```

Directory-C
File.txt

```
ID  Value location
 1   21     9
 2   68     3
 3   42     5
```

My output should be a combined table as follows :

```
ID  Directory-A  Directory-B  Directory-C
 1   50              07           21
 2   56              06           68
 3   26              02           42
```

My perl script merges all the columns from the file not the particular column I am interested in and I do not know how to rename the header.
Many thanks for suggestions.

Comment: If you would like help with your script, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your files are tab separated you could do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @result;
my @files = ( "directory-a/file.txt", "directory-b/file.txt", "directory-c/file.txt" );

my $i = 0;
foreach my $filename ( @files ) {
    $result[ $i ] = [];
    open( my $file, "<", $filename );
    while ( my $line = <$file> ) {
        my @columns = split( /\t/, $line );
        push( @{ $result[ $i ] }, $columns[1] ); # getting values only from the column we need
    }
    close $file;
    $i++;
}

my $max_count = 0;
foreach my $column ( @result ) {
    $max_count = scalar( @$column ) if ( scalar( @$column ) > $max_count );
}

open ( my $file, ">", "result.txt" );
for ( 0 .. $max_count - 1 ) {
    my @row;
    foreach my $col ( @result ) {
        my $value = shift( @$col ) || "";
        push( @row, $value );       
    }
    print $file join( "\t", @row ), "\n";
};
close $file;
```